# Таблица с помощью ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

есть допустим таблица из 2 столбцов.Она создается при нажатии на кнопку без перезагрузки страницы. Значения для таблицы берутся из БД. Как сделать,что бы 1 столбец это "Список студентов" это 1 запрос к бд, а 2 столбец это допустим предметы , но он вертикальный и это уже 2 запрос.
Вот что-то типа такого должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То,что выделено красным это как бы данные из первого запроса, а остальные данные из 2 запроса. То есть мне группа говоря из 2 таблиц надо сделать 1 .Помогите пожалуйста, я пробовал, но не особо получилось.
Это index.php, На которой строится таблица в соответствии с выбранными select'ми.

```
    <body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
       <div class="container container_S ">
           <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 ">Группа</div>
                 <div class="col-md-4 ">
                     <select name="akgroup" id="akgroup_S" >
                           <option value="-1" selected="selected">- выберите группу -</option>

                        <?  
                             while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getakgrp)) 
                             {
                                 echo('<option  value="' . $result["AKGRP1"] . '">' . $result["AKGRP2R"]);
                            } 
                             ?>
                        </select>

                 </div>  
                       <div class="col-md-2">Номер семестра</div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select name="semestr" id="semestr_S">
                         <option value="0" selected>- выберите семестр -</option>

                        <?  
                             while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getSemestr)) 
                             {
                                 echo('<option  value="' . $result["sem1"] . '">' . $result["sem2"]);
                            } 
                             ?>

                     </select>
                 </div>  
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">Учебный год</div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                     <select name="academicYear" id="academicYear_S" >
                         <option value="0" selected="selected">- выберите Учебный год -</option>

                            <?  
                             while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getAcademYear))
                             {
                        echo('<option value="' . $result["uchgod1"] . '">' . $result["uchgod2"]);
                             }
                             ?>
                     </select>
                 </div> 
                <div class="col-md-4">
                     <input type="button" name="List_Ved" class="btn btn-success" id="List_Ved" value="Переглянути семестроову відомість">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                     <input type="button" name="Back_Menu" class="btn btn-success" id="Back_Menu" value="Назад" onClick='location.href="main.php"'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

ajax файл

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#List_Ved').bind("click", function () {
    $("#div_table_list").remove();
     if($("#akgroup").val()==-1 || $("#semestr_S").val()==0 || $("#academicYear_S").val()==0){
    alert("Будь ласка заповніть всі  поля.");
    return false;
  }
    $.ajax({
        url: "poseschenie_zanyatiy.actions.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            "ajax": "4",
             "group_List": $('#akgroup_S').val(),
             "semestr_List": $('#semestr_S').val(),
             "academYear_List": $('#academicYear_S').val()
        },
        success: function (output_List) {

            $("div.container_S").append($(output_List));

        }
    });
});
});
```

А тут выполняем запрос к БД.

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] == 4){
$group_List=$_POST['group_List'];    
$semestr_List=$_POST['semestr_List'];
$academYear_List=$_POST['academYear_List'];
$tbl_List="<div class='row' id='div_table_list'>
           <div class='col-md-12'>
                                <table name='List'>

                                    <tr class='table_tbl_List'>
                                     <td>ФІО студентів</td>
                                     <td>Оцінки</td>                           
                                     </tr>";
if ($result = $mysqli->query("select * from usp
                            inner join st on st.ST_ID=usp.USP1
                            inner join predm on predm.predm1=usp.USP4
                            Where st_akgrp='$group_List'
                            and usp2='$semestr_List'
                            and usp3='$academYear_List' 
                            "
                            )) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $sur_st = $row['ST_F1U'];
            $id_stud = $row['ST_ID'];
            $name_stud = $row['ST_F2U'];
            $patronymic_stud = $row['ST_F3U'];
            $marks_100=$row['USP6_100'];
            $marks_ECTS=$row['USP6'];
            $marks=$row['USP6ECTS'];
            $subject_List=$row['predm2u'];
              $tbl_List .= "

                <tr title=$id_stud >
                <td> $sur_st $name_stud  $patronymic_stud </td>
                <td> $marks_100 $marks_ECTS $marks </td>
                <td> $subject_List </td>
                </tr>
                ";


         }
}
$res_table_list.="</table>  </div></div>";
echo  $tbl_List;


}
```

Comment: Приведите код, который вы пробовали.

Comment: так надо ?https://jsfiddle.net/jbpLnx0e/1/

Comment: вы хотите с помощью ajax заполнить таблицу, но сами даже ничего не написали?

Comment: Я добавил код. Пробовал, но  там данные для таблицы берутся с помощью 1-ой таблицы из бд, а мне надо взять данные из 2-ух и поместить это всё в одну таблицу.

Comment: "так надо ?jsfiddle.net/jbpLnx0e/1 " Ну представления  таблицы -да, спасибо. Но это не самая главная проблема. А главной проблемой является размещения данных на ней, но все равно  спасибо за помощь, хотя бы как её строить я уже знаю.